# Bottom display a message on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a message at the bottom when someone click on checkbox.

```
<style>
.stick {
    background-color: red;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="col-md-12" id="compare" style="stick; display:none;"> 
      <div class="separator"></div>
      <div class="alert alert-info text-md-center">
        <span class="text-md-center">
          <button class="btn">
         My message
        </span>
      </div> 
</div>
<script>

function showProductsCompare() {
    document.getElementById('compare').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

until now, all it's correct, the message appear on the page when the code is inserted

but I tried to make a sticky message like this page https://www.homedepot.com/s/french%2520door%2520refrigerators?NCNI-5 (click on the checkbox.

I don't find example or to make that.

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding css for your "compare" element using: `position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 100px`?

Comment: Might as well add `width: 100%; left: 0` to match the same CSS as the one you linked in that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
.stick {
    background-color: red;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    buttom: 0;
}
```

You will need to give the div a class of "stick":

```
<div class="col-md-12 stick" id="compare" style="stick; display:none;">
```

Comment: No it don't work. code update above. When I click on the checkbox, the message is always at the same place, complety at the bottom of the page., look the link and clic on  2 checkbox and go to bottom. the bar appear alwyas at the bottom.

Comment: Ok, works, buttom =>bottom and with a  z-index: 10000; could better.